# Test an Object and determine if it is of Class x

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to write a method that will iterate over an `ArrayList` and then determine if the objects stored inside are either of `ClassA` or `ClassB` (these classes Extend class Types), if they are, an `int` variable (`counter`) will be incremented and the count of `ClassA` + `ClassB` objects will be returned.

I am trying to do something like:

```
for(Types type : typeList) {
    if( type.getClass().equals(ClassA) || (type.getClass().equals(ClassB) ) {
        counter++;
    }
}
return counter;
```

However, this is wrong. Any guidance on how to do this is much appreciated. I'm thinking that I could create 'dummy' objects of `ClassA` and `ClassB` to compare, however there has to be a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `isAssignableFrom` method of the `Class` class.  It tells you whether one class or interface is a supertype of another.  Is that what you mean?  If not, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(Types type : typeList) {
    if( type.getClass().equals(ClassA.class) || (type.getClass().equals(ClassB.class) ) {
        counter++;
    }
}
return counter;
```

or preferably

```
for(Types type : typeList) {
    if(type instanceof ClassA || type instanceof ClassB) {
        counter++;
    }
}
return counter;
```

EDIT: I must point out a difference between these two ways. The first does not count any subclasses of `ClassA` and `ClassB`. The second does. For the first, use `isInstance` instead of `equals` if you want to count subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the instanceof-operator.

```
for(Types type : typeList) {
    if( type instanceof ClassA || type instanceof ClassB ) {
        counter++;
    }
}
return counter;
```

Also note, that if you have `null` in your list, this approach would still return false.
If you use the

```
type.getClass().equals(ClassA.class)
```

approach, it will throw a NullPointerException when `null` is encountered.

Further `instanceof` and `type.getClass().equals(ClassA.class)` does not the same thing.
Instanceof also returns `true`, if type is a subclass of either ClassA or ClassB.
`type.getClass().equals(ClassA.class)` evaluates only to `true`, if type is an instance of ClassA and not one of their subclasses.

Comment: I too would go with this approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Your original error is because you are referring to the type name itself, not its `Class`; to get a type's `Class` object, use `.class`, e.g.:

```
type.getClass().equals(ClassA.class)
```

You can just use `instanceof`, e.g.:

```
for (Types type : typeList) {
    if (type instanceof ClassA || type instanceof ClassB) {
        counter ++;
    }
}
```

By the way, `getClass().equals(...)` is not equivalent to `instanceof`; for that you'd want to use `ClassA.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getClass())`.

Alternatively, if it makes sense semantically, you could have the objects expose properties that determine if they should be counted or not, e.g.:

```
// Base, for example:
public abstract class Types {
    abstract public boolean isInteresting();
}

// Then: 
public ClassA extends Types { 
    @Override public boolean isInteresting() { return true; }
}

public ClassB extends Types { 
    @Override public boolean isInteresting() { return true; }
}

public ClassC extends Types { 
    @Override public boolean isInteresting() { return false; }
}

// Later:
int countInterestingObjects (ArrayList<Types> typeList) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (Types type : typeList) {
        if (type.isInteresting()) {
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```